# Can “pour” be used at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: traduction, prépositions

I just learnt that the preposition *pour* could mean *in regards to* or *as for* from [this website](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/pour/).

My question is the following: **Can *pour* be used at the beginning of a sentence?**
I am aware that we can begin a sentence with a prepositional phrase, well this is true at least for English. Assuming that this is true for French, there's no problem with beginning the sentence with *pour*.

For example, say if I wanted to say in French

> In regards to her, I don't love her anymore.

I think the translation would be

> Pour elle, je ne l'aime plus.

I also know that a stressed pronoun follows prepositions.

But Google Translates it as

> En ce qui la concerne, je ne l'aime plus.

Which is correct? Is my translation correct or Google's or both?

Comment: As a side remark. Normally, Je does not need a capital J as in the relevant English pronoun I, unless it starts a sentence. In a text like the Bible one may encounter Je in other cases with reference to God.

Answer (score 4):

> "Pour vous rendre service, je vais répondre à votre question."
>
> "Pour ne pas vous décevoir, je vais jouer cette sonate."

In your example, I would rather write

> "Quant à elle, je ne l'aime plus."

Answer (score 1):

You can start your sentence with *pour*, but for your example, you cannot just say *pour elle* and have it mean *as for her*. That's because in *pour elle*, the object will be understood as the beneficiary of some action. It would either mean something like *for her own good* or *from her point of view* rather than *in regards to her*.

If you really want to start with *pour*, you can use *pour ce qui*, which will help avoid the misunderstanding:

> Pour ce qui la concerne, ...
>
> Pour ce qui est de cette femme, ...

Comment: `pour elle, je ne l'aime plus` could mean `acording to her/ in her opinion, I don't love her anymore`

Comment: @Flying_whale thanks, added into answer

Comment: What does 'Pour ce qui la concerne,' and 'Pour ce qui est de cette femme,' mean ?

Comment: @CubbyKushi "Pour ce qui la concerne" = *As regards her*; "Pour ce qui est de cette femme" = *As for this woman*

Comment: Do you mean 'As regards to her'?

Comment: @CubbyKushi this is getting a little off-topic but I did mean *as regards her*. A quick search online confirmed that *as regards sthg* is proper rather than **as regards to sthg*

Answer (score 1):

*Pour elle, je ferais n'importe quoi* is correct.

*Pour elle, je ne l'aime plus* doesn't have the meaning you want in french (in another context, that could mean that she thinks you don't love her anymore).

Google's version is more accurate. But as [Bernard Massé](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29770/16699) suggested, *Quant à elle* works too.

Answer (score 0):

**Sentences originally adopted from: "A French Reference Grammar" by H. Ferrar and slightly modified by me. But see also the remarks of @jlliagre in the associated comments.**

*Pour* (among the many meanings) may express personal concern:

> Pour ma part, je m'abstiendrai. Personally, I shall abstain.

It may start a phrase when it also expresses:

1. By way of:

> Pour couverture il avait un sac. For a blanket he had a sack.
>   (As @jlliagre suggests, it is better here to use `comme couverture`.)

2. Considering

> Pour son âge/pour un enfant, il lit bien.

3. Purpose

> Pour le terminer, il faut s’entraîner.
>
> Pour n'être pas vu, il nous faut sortir la nuit.
>   (As @jlliagre remarks it is better to use `pour ne pas être vu` instead.)

Comment: *Il n'avait pour couverture qu'un sac* is fine but I prefer to use *comme* instead of *pour* in *comme couverture, il avait **un** sac*. Are you sure "guide" translates *sac*?  Unless the plan is to train to finish off (i.e. kill) people or animals, better to write *pour le terminer, il faut s'entraîner* instead of *achever*. Use *pour ne pas être vu* instead of *pour n'être pas vu*.

Comment: The examples (with some slight modifications) are from my (classic:-)!) reference:  A French Reference Grammar, p. 285, H. Ferrar (Oxford University Press, 1967, reprinted with corrections 1988).

Comment: For instance the author has a whole subsection for pour and its uses. For purpose he gives as an example `pour l'achever` et c'est moi qui remplis la phrase avec `il faut s'entraîner`. Concernant le premier exemple j'ai fait une faute. Je vais le corriger. Merci. En revanche, `pour n'être pas vu`, je l'ai vu dans le livre. Je remplis la phrase avec `il nous faut sortir la nuit`. Je vous fais confiance quand même. Je vais modifier la structure:-)!

Comment: I missed another issue: *pour moi, je m'abstiendrai* should definitely be *pour ma part, je m'abstiendrai*. By the way, *pour n'être pas vu* is not incorrect, it just sounds old fashioned or posh. This might be obvious but it's either *pour son age* or *pour un enfant*, not both in the same sentence.

Comment: Je crois devoir changer le livre et consulter un autre:-)! `Pour moi `j'abstiendrai` je l'ai vu dans le livre. Je pense qu'il y a une faute (il manque le prénom réflexif me comme tu indique). En plus, tu as raison pour le pléonasme. Mais c'est un exemple du livre de nouveau...Je vais le modifier.

Comment: Oui, il faut vraiment changer de livre de français s'il est vraiment écrit *pour moi, j'abstiendrai* dedans !

Comment: C'est noté! J'aime ce livre car il est concis et complet mais il faut avouer que j'y ai trouvé des fautes sérieuses !